# Call a function dependent on the value inside an array with SPFx and react

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I coded a template that pushes values from a SharePoint List into an array. I want to change the image inside the array depending on a value that is inside an array.

The value should function like a traffic light function. So if the value is "Green", the template should use a green traffic light image. If "Yellow" then a yellow image.

Here is my code so far:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IWebPartPoCswProps> {
    const {
      description,
      isDarkTheme,
      environmentMessage,
      hasTeamsContext,
      userDisplayName
    } = this.props;
    
    let project =[];
    
    this.state.ProjectFilterItem.forEach((item:IListItem)=> project.push(
       
      <div className={styles.containerGrid}>
        
        <div className={styles.ProjectTitleHeader}>item 1 {item.Title}</div>
        <div className={styles.ProjectStatusTrafficLight}>item 2 TrafficLight {item.TrafficLight?.Title}</div>
        <div className={styles.ProjectStartdate}>item 3 {item.StartDate}</div>
        <div className={styles.ProjectEnddate}> item 4 {item.EndDate}</div>
        <div className={styles.ProjectStatus}>item 5 {item.ProjectStatus?.Title}</div>
        <div className={styles.ProjectPhase}>item 6 {item.ProjectPhase?.Title}</div>
      </div>
    ))
  

    return (
      <section className={`${styles.webPartPoCsw} ${hasTeamsContext ? styles.teams : ''}`}>
        <div className={styles.welcome}>
          <h2>Well done, {escape(userDisplayName)}!</h2>
          <div>{environmentMessage}</div>
          <div>Web part property value: <strong>{escape(description)}</strong></div>
        </div>
 
      
        <div>
           {this.state.ProjectFilterItem[0].TrafficLight.Title.toString()}
          
          {project}
        </div>
       
      </section>
    
     );
    }
}
```

I can't read the value of the TrafficLight array position. Maybe you can help me. e.g.

```
If (ValueTrafficlight =="Green"){
      valueLight="Green url"
}
```

Comment: Is `TrafficLight` of type array? Is it nested inside `ProjectFilterItem`?

Comment: Yes. You can get the value from this line: {item.TrafficLight?.Title} here is the value Green, Yellow or Red

Comment: Then what is the problem exactly? Are you unable to use `If (item.TrafficLight && item.TrafficLight.Title == "Green"){ }`. From where the image URL will be coming, dynamically or static URLs hard coded?

Comment: I don't know how to use conditional rendering in my template. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering in template like this:

```
{
    if (item.TrafficLight && item.TrafficLight.Title == "Green") {
        return <img src="green.jpg" />
    } else if (item.TrafficLight && item.TrafficLight.Title == "Yellow") {
        return <img src="yellow.jpg" />
    } else {
        return <img src="red.jpg" />
    }
}
```

You can change the image URLs as per your requirements.

Check below links for conditional rendering in react:

1. [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
2. [Conditional Rendering in React](https://flexiple.com/react/conditional-rendering-in-react)
3. [7 Ways to Implement Conditional Rendering in React Applications](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-ways-to-implement-conditional-rendering-in-react-applications)

Comment: That's not working for me. I needs to be different, but still figure out how.

Comment: Can you explain in details how you want it? Reference links in my answer does not help you with conditional rendering? There are multiple ways to achieve conditional rendering in react, read the articles in above links once.

Comment: Is it working for you now? You can also try switch or ternary operator approach from 3rd link in my answer. let me know if you still need help with this.

Comment: Please update this thread, is it working for you now?